# Android Room : How to loop on query result?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have a SQL table "Diag" like this :
| idDossier | Id             |
| 2231070   | 1              |
| 2231070   | 2              |
| 2231070   | 3              |
| 2231070   | 4              |
| 1907043   | 5              |
| 1907043   | 6              |
| 1907043   | 7              |

And i would like to have the greastest Id foreach IdDossier like this :
| idDossier | Id            |
| 1907043   | 7             |
| 2231070   | 5             |

I manage to do it this request in "BD Browser for SQLite" :

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT idDossier, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idDossier ORDER BY id DESC) as rn FROM old_diagnostic)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

But unfortunately, "PARTITION BY" doesn't work in Room, I got this error :

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

So I would like to know if there something like this pseudo-code :

```
values = SELECT DISTINCT(idDossier) FROM Diag

foreach(x in values){
  SELECT *, MAX(id) FROM Diag where idDossier = x
}
```

Is it possible ? If not, how can I have achieve this without using "PARTITION BY" ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT idDossier, MAX(id) as maxID FROM <TableName> GROUP BY idDossier
```

Also, you can use raw query. [Reference Documentation for raw query](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery#observedEntities())

Comment: Just like that... Well, it works, thanks a lot !

Comment: For those who want to remove the maxID column, here is the request I made :
`WITH selection AS
(SELECT *, MAX(id) FROM diagnostic GROUP BY idDossier)
SELECT idDossier, id FROM selection`